# SettingWithCopyWarning when modifying column inplace

Tags: python, pandas

There was a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) discussing why and how to deal with this. But it was 7 years ago. I am using Python 3.9, pandas 1.3.3. I want to modify a column `timestamp` in my data frame as following:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda ts: some_func(ts))
```

I got the same warning. So I tried these solutions:

```
df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda ts: some_func(ts))
df['timestamp'] = df.loc[:, 'timestamp'].map(lambda ts: some_func(ts))
```

But both of them still give the same warning. If I don't want to suppress the warning and instead solve it properly, how should I revise this line of code?

Comment: Is your `df` is a slice of another one, e.g. `df = big_df[big_df['a']>b]`? If so, you need `df = df.copy()`. Also, `map(some_func)` is the same with `map(lambda ts: some_func(ts))`.

Comment: Thanks. You're right !